# How to use intellisense with react.js JSX code embedded in Javascript in VS 2015 Update 1?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I'm trying to make my Visual Studio 2015 Professional Update 1 deal with JSX code that is embedded in react.js Javascript code in an ASP.NET MVC project's view. According to several blog posts, Update 1 is supposed to support JSX, but I can't figure out how to make it happen, so I hope that one of you ran into the same issue and can point me in the right direction.

I installed *react.js* (0.14.7) via Nuget and included the two script files in the view as you can see below in a simple test page. Right now Intellisense gets mad at all places where JSX comes into play, e.g. in the render method of the ButtonCounter component.

Is there some option I need to set deep in the VS guts? Thanks in advance!

```
<script src="~/Scripts/react/react-with-addons.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/react/react-dom.js"></script>

<article>
    <div id="#react-container">
    </div>
</article>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var ButtonCounter = React.createClass({
        style: function() {
            return {backgroundColor: this.props.colour};
        },

        render: function() {
            return(
              <div>
                <h1>{this.props.colour} counter</h1> // (3)
                <button style={this.style()}
            onClick={this.add}>+</button>

    <p>Current count:
                <span>{this.state.count}</span>
              </p>
              <hr />
            </div>
          );
        }
    });

    var App = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
            return {colours: ['red', 'green', 'blue']};
        },

        buttons: function() {
            return this.state.colours.map(function(colour) {
                return(<ButtonCounter colour={colour} />);
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        return(
          <div>{this.buttons()}</div>
        );
    }
    });

    React.render(<App />,
      document.querySelector('#react-container'));

</script>
```